# how to use autocomplete with full body search in apostrophe cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

right now I have something similar to

```
 var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req, { highSearchText:  {$regex: new RegExp(self.apos.utils.regExpQuote(req.query.search), 'i') }  } )

 cursor.queryToFilters({ highSearchText:  {$regex: new RegExp(self.apos.utils.regExpQuote(req.query.search), 'i') }  }, 'public')

.perPage(self.perPage);
```

And I am trying to figure out a way to implement [autocomplete](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-docs/server-apostrophe-cursor.html#autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

As you know I'm the head of the Apostrophe team at P'unk Avenue.

You're trying way, way, way too hard (:

Name your search field "autocomplete" in your form.

Then do this:

```
var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req, {})
  .queryToFilters(req.query, 'public')
  .perPage(self.perPage);
};
```

Really... that's it. The whole purpose of `queryToFilters` is to basically just do this (not quite, see below for security notes on what it really does):

```
// DON'T DO THIS, JUST GIVES YOU AN IDEA OF WHAT'S GOING ON
_.each(req.query, function(val, key) {
  cursor[key](val);
});
```

It invokes cursor methods with the same name as the properties of `req.query` (well, almost).

Of course that would be unsafe, but `queryToFilters` specifically makes sure the methods in question are cursor filters that are marked as `safeFor: 'public'` and runs their sanitizers too.

`autocomplete` is such a cursor filter, so... boom, we're done.

Also, I see you are working with `self.apos.docs.find` directly. I assume you are doing that because you want ALL types of docs to come back from the query, in which case you are doing the right thing.

In case it is not clear, if you're not even working with a query string in the first place, you can just call `autocomplete` directly with whatever it is you do have:

```
cursor.autocomplete('startofaword');
```

Hope this is helpful!